# How can I run a migration on Heroku when receiving bundle install error message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I was deploying some code to a staging environment and realized I had to run a migration so I ran

`heroku run rake db:migrate`

and got this error:

```
Could not find json-1.8.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Now if I run ANY `heroku` command I get the same error. That include `heroku run bundle`, `heroku run bundle exec`, etc.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: `heroku run bundle install`?

Comment: yeah that throws the same error... I just gem installed json but now I'm getting a really weird segmentation fault error on heroku run rake db:migrate so maybe we're getting somewhere?

Comment: just type $ heroku , if it results same, then there is problem in heroku-toolbelt.

Comment: Run `bundle install` locally and check if Gemfile.lock has changed or not. If it did, commit this change and try redeploy.